# gridview click event when autogeneratecolumns

Tags: c#

If I just drop a gridview on my page (AutoGenerateColumns = true) and then wire up a datasource on the code-behind, is there a way to get a click event to occur in each cell for certain columns? I know I can add buttons,checkboxes, etc from designer. I was just wondering if I can do it quick and easy with AutoGenerateColumns on.

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataControlFieldCell c = e.Row.Cells[2] as DataControlFieldCell;
 //Maybe somehow put a click event here.       

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add client-side `onclick` event and pass cell's (TD) ID there:

```
c.Attributes["onclick"] = "myJSfunction('" + c.ClientID + "')";
```

And perform some logic on client side, calling server if needed either via some Button/LinkButton `click()` method, calling `__doPostBack()` on some other control or even making AJAX call.